# Can we have a linux terminal chat client for gmail?

Tags: gmail, instant-messaging, google-talk, chat

Does a gmail terminal chat client exist or anyway one can write it?

Comment: Don't you already have it on the Gmail UI?

Comment: Yes, I do. But I want to do it through terminal.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  Gmail uses the Jabber chat protocol which has been around for much longer than gchat and  is supported by a number of open source command line chatting programs.  One of my favorite terminal chat clients is [Centericq](http://konst.org.ua/centericq/) which supports jabber along with many other chat protocol.  It is ncurses based:

[image]

To connect to gchat use these settings:

```
Username: Your Google Talk username (without any @ symbol or domain information)
Password: Your password
Login Server: Enter the portion of your email address after the @ symbol. For example, gordon@example.com will enter example.com as the Login Server value.
Use SSL: Yes
Manually specify connection host: Yes
Host: talk.google.com
Port: 5223
Keep connection alive: Yes
```

Comment: Pidgin and Irssi also support jabber (and XMPP for facebook chat)

Comment: As of 2023 XMPP no longer works.

Answer (score 4):

Part of the Pidgin IM client is a terminal based client called Finch. Take a look at the [Using Finch page](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Finch) on the Pidgin wiki.

Answer (score 2):

[Bitlbee](http://www.bitlbee.org) provides an IRC interface to most of the common chat protocols. Mix with Irssi or your CLI IRC client of choice.

Answer (score 1):

[MCabber](http://mcabber.com/) should also work just fine. It supports OTR also (which is crucial if we talk about Google and nowadays internet).

(MCabber is my favorite by the way. I tried all the alternatives but this seemed to be the best so far. It just works, it's just excellent.)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install irssi-plugin-xmpp
```